# Generic Response Format in C# JSON API

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently mapping everything that I have to a DTO which follows the same kind of formatting, it has attributes and sometimes meta nested within.

An example response is:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "attributes": {
    "name": "Lebz",
    "email": "lebbbz@example.com"
  },
  "meta": {
    "isAdmin": true
  }
}
```

And the way in which I get to this I am doing the following class mapping:

```cs
public class UserDto : BaseDto<UserDto, User>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public UserAttributes Attributes { get; set; } = default!;

    public UserMeta Meta { get; set; } = default!;
    
    public override void AddCustomMappings()
    {
        SetCustomMappingsInverse()
            .Map(dto => dto.Attributes.Name, user => user.Name)
            .Map(dto => dto.Attributes.Email, user => user.Email)
            .Map(dto => dto.Meta.IsAdmin, user => user.IsAdmin);
    }
}

public class UserAttributes
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

    public string Email { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class UserMeta
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

This is quite a lot of manual entry and mapping in order to achieve something that is pretty straight forward but due to the legacy of the project I need to keep the properties nested within the attributes and meta some method.

I was looking in there is a way to automatically map through a class potentially which is dynamic.

I like having to create the `UserAttributes` and `UserMeta` as it defines, but I wanted to know if there was a way to automatically map between this and the `AddCustomMappings()` method.

So the class would just be:

```
public class UserDto : BaseDto<UserDto, User>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
  public Meta Meta { get; set; }
}

internal class Attributes 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}

internal class Meta
{
  public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated as all DTO will essentially be constructed like the above but with different attributes defined.

This application uses Mapster in the background.